# Chart.js: adding a custom label to each item, and displaying it with a custom tooltip

Tags: chart.js

I'm building my data items like this:

```
data.push({ x: moment(new Date(e.StartDate)).week(), y: e.title, label:`${e.title} ${e.type} ${e.percentage}%` });
```

How do I write a custom tooltip callback to display the label string?

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js Docs show a complete description for custom tooltips:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips

and also examples:

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-line.html

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-pie.html

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-points.html

Comment: I tried with all these links, They only allows only x & y axis data in tooltip, there are other things in json, need to show as a tooltip, but can't do this.